# What's wrong with my ClientConnection class? C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winsock2

Assume that there's no problem with my header file and some included library. I'm using Winsock2.

```
//main.cpp and this code is okie, I omit some codes for readable reason
SOCKET ClientSocket;
ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
cout <<"a client is connected" << endl;
ClientConnection connection(ClientSocket);
connection.run();

//ClientConnection.h I tested any function and it's okie
class ClientConnection{
    private:
        SOCKET connectedSocket;
        bool connected;
    public:
        ClientConnection(const ClientConnection &con);
        ClientConnection(SOCKET s);
        int processMessage(string message);
        void sendMessage(string message);
        string recvMessage();
        int run();
        void printSomething(); //function just print something such as :"Here"
};
```

In `run()` function, I call the `recvMessage()` to get the message from client then I call `processMessage(message)`. This is my `processMessage(message)` and `sendMessage`:

```
void ClientConnection::sendMessage(string mess){
    const char* sendBuff = mess.c_str();    
    int error = send(this->connectedSocket,sendBuff, (int)strlen(sendBuff), 0);
    delete sendBuff;
    return ;
}
int ClientConnection::processMessage(string message){
    cout << "This is message from client:\n" << message << endl;
    ImageProcessingPlugin *plugin = new ImageProcessingPlugin();
    plugin-> processMessage( *this, message);
    delete plugin;
    return 0;
}
```

This is ImageProcessingPlugin:

```
// ImageProcessingPlugin.h
class ImageProcessingPlugin : public Plugin{
public:
    ImageProcessingPlugin();
    void processMessage(const ClientConnection &connection, string message);
};
// ImageProcessingPlugin.cpp
void ImageProcessingPlugin::processMessage(const ClientConnection& _connection,  string message){
    ClientConnection connection(_connection);
    connection.printSomething() // It's okie
    connection.sendMessage("Server received"); // Problem goes here!!
    return;
}
```

After debugging, when I call `printSomething()` in `plugin->processMessage`, it's still ok, but when I go to `sendMessage`, the client still got the message "Server received" from server, but there was an error: "_Block_Type_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)"! Anyone can solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your deleting `delete sendBuff;` here, but you never allocated the memory yourself. Try removing that line.

Comment: It's really help! but, Why i have to remove `delete sendbuff` here?

Comment: @Kingfisher:`std::string` manages the memory for you, so you should never call `delete` on memory managed by `std::string`.